# RESTEasy client framework authentication credentials

Tags: java, http, jax-rs, resteasy

RESTEasy (a JAX-RS implementation) has a nice client framework, eg:

```
ServiceApi client = ProxyFactory.create(ServiceApi.class, baseUri);
```

How do you provide HTTP authentication credentials to this client?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Credentials can be provided by using ClientExecutor.

```
   Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userId, password);
   HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
   httpClient.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);
   httpClient.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);

   ClientExecutor clientExecutor = new ApacheHttpClientExecutor(httpClient);

   ServiceApi client = ProxyFactory.create(ServiceApi.class, baseUri, clientExecutor);
```

Answer (score 16):

jnorris's answer uses some deprecated classes.  Here is an updated way that uses non-deprecated classes.

```
    import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.apache.http.auth.Credentials;
    import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    ...
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName,
            password);
    httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
            org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

    ClientExecutor clientExecutor = new ApacheHttpClient4Executor(
            httpClient);
    proxy = ProxyFactory
            .create(UserAccessProxy.class, host, clientExecutor);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this (with RestEasy 2.3.1) :

```
//(...imports...)
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponse;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.executors.ApacheHttpClient4Executor;

//(...code...)
private static final String ENDPOINT = "the_rest_endpoint_here";

String username = "<user_name>";
String password = "<password>";

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
                        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
ApacheHttpClient4Executor executer = new ApacheHttpClient4Executor(client);

ClientRequest req = new ClientRequest(ENDPOINT, executer);

ClientResponse<String> res = req.get(String.class);
System.out.println(res.getEntity());
res.close();
```

...or with RestEasy 3.0.18

```
//(...imports...)
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.BasicAuthentication;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClient;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyWebTarget;

//(...code...)
private static final String ENDPOINT = "the_rest_endpoint_here";

String usertoken = "<user_token>";
String password = "<password>";

//with proxy(comment this if not using)
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
            .defaultProxy("my_proxy", 8080, "http")
            .build();

ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(ENDPOINT);
target.register(new BasicAuthentication(usertoken, password));

Response response = target.request().get();
System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
response.close();
```